# How can I specify JAXB customizations externally to a WSDL file?

Tags: jaxb, wsdl, jax-ws, wsimport

I have a WSDL file for a service implemented in .NET. I also have the same file with some "customizations" made by a 3rd-party to make the file tolerable to `wsimport`, mostly of the form:

```
<s:annotation>
  <s:appinfo>
    <jaxb:property name="result"/>
  </s:appinfo>
</s:annotation>
```

I'd like to be able to process the *original* WSDL from the vendor plus these overrides, but I'd like to specify them externally. I see that I can use the `-b` option for `wsimport` for "binding files" and I've tried to write an override file that currently looks like this:

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
  xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='MyElementResult']">
    <jxb:property name="result"/>
  </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

I've verified that "MyElementName" does in fact exist, in an element found here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
     xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/"
     xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
     xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
     xmlns:tns="vendor-uri"
     xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:s2="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/"
     xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
     xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
     targetNamespace="vendor-namespace"
     xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

  [...]
  <s:element name="MyElementResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MyElementResult" type="tns:Result" />
```

I'm getting this warning (and therefore no changes) from `wsimport`:

```
[ERROR] XPath evaluation of "//xs:element[@name='MyElementResult']" results in empty target node
  line 4 of file:/Users/..../wsdl/custom-bindings.xjb
```

Am I missing something in my declaration(s)? Do I have my XPath expression incorrect? If I get my XPath/overrides working, is it formatted correctly in order to achieve the same result as if I had edited the original WSDL?

Is this even possible using external files, or will I have to re-modify any future versions of the WSDL with these same changes?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use the same namespace alias `s` in your override file as the original WSDL file has for the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`, instead of the alias `xs` that you have above?

Comment: Nope: when I use `xmlns:s` and then `//s:element` in the selector, I get the same error. I was kind of hoping that `wsimport` was just stupid and this would be the solution, but fortunately `wsimport` appears to treat XML properly and not worry when two different documents use different namespace names (which is the whole point of namespaces).

Comment: If you change the XPath expression do you get any different results?  For example, specifying an absolute path, different but sufficiently equivalent matching criteria, etc.

Comment: Looks like no: I changed the XPath to simply `//s:element` and I get the same error: `[ERROR] XPath evaluation of "//s:element" results in empty target node`

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe I should just pre-process the WSDL myself using XSLT instead of relying on `wsimport` to do it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the schema location in your bindings XML file.

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
     xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jxb:bindings 
         schemaLocation="PATH_TO_YOUR_WSDL#types?schema1"
         node="//xs:schema[@targetNamespace='SCHEMA_NAMESPACE']">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='MyElementResult']">
            <jxb:property name="result"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

The `#types?schema1` after the WSDL file name will specify which schema in the WSDL you are binding, starting at 1.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the problem, but I may have done it incorrectly. If my WSDL file is called `foo.wsdl`, do I just literally use `<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="foo.wsdl#types?schema1">` or is it more nuanced than that? (Hang on... there are multiple schemas in the WSDL file.. perhaps I have to repeat all that stuff...).

Comment: I added the following to the example: `node="//xs:schema[@targetNamespace='SCHEMA_NAMESPACE']"`. Make sure that the SCHEMA_NAMESPACE value you provide matches the targetNamespace attribute on the schema you are trying to select.

Comment: I'm making progress, here. Just coming back to this after 2 years takes some time :)

Comment: just <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="PATH_TO_YOUR_WSDL"> should be sufficient as your first bindings node.